# How can I get two Sign-in with Google buttons executing different actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-signin

As title says, I have two custom Sign-In with Google buttons and I want each button redirects to a certain link but when I test an example both buttons execute the same action of the second button. This is my example displaying alerts in this case:

[image]

```
<style>
#customButton01{width:280px;background:url(mysite.com/btn01.jpg) no-repeat;height:60px;cursor:pointer;}
#customButton02{width:280px;background:url(mysite.com/btn02.jpg) no-repeat;height:60px;cursor:pointer;}
</style>
```

This **customButton01** button displays an alert "Button 01" after login with gmail account, this is the code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
<script>
var googleUser = {};
var startApp = function() {
gapi.load('auth2', function(){

  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'myID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',

  });
  attachSignin(document.getElementById('customButton01'));
});
};

function attachSignin(element) {
   console.log(element.id);
   auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
    function(googleUser) {                           

        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                'userId': 'me'
            });

            request.execute(function (resp) {
                alert("Button 01"); //Display an alert after login
            });

        });
    }, function(error) {
      //alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
    });
 }
</script>

<script>
function onSuccess(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        //Display the user details
        request.execute(function (resp) {                    
            signOut();                                  
        });
    });
}
function onFailure(error) {
    alert(error);
}
function renderButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
    });
}
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        //$('.userContent').html('');
        //$('#gSignIn').slideDown('slow');
    });
}
</script>

<hr style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 10px;border-top: 1px solid #DDD;">
<div id="customButton01" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
<script>startApp();</script>
```

In **customButton02** button is the same code but with the difference of display an alert "Button 02":

```
<script>
var googleUser = {};
var startApp2 = function() {
gapi.load('auth2', function(){
  // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'myID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
    // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
    //scope: 'additional_scope'
  });
  attachSignin(document.getElementById('customButton02'));
});
};

function attachSignin(element) {
console.log(element.id);
auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
    function(googleUser) {                           

        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
            var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                'userId': 'me'
            });

            request.execute(function (resp) {
                //alert(resp.name.givenName);
                alert("Button 02"); //Display another alert
            });

        });
    }, function(error) {
      //alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
    });
}
</script>

(...)

<hr style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 10px;border-top: 1px solid #DDD;">
<div id="customButton02" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
<script>startApp2();</script>
```

So I want when I sign-in clicking on **"Sign-In Button01"** displays "Button 01" alert, and when I sign-in clicking on **"Sign-In Button02"** displays "Button 02" alert, but actually both buttons display the same "Button 02" alert, I tried to change function name but it's still the same.

How can I modify it?

I'd like some help.

Comment: Would be great if you could set it up in a fiddle

Comment: whats renderButton and gSignIn in customButton01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two definitions for the same function `attachSignin`, so the 2nd erase the 1st.

So either you name the two of them with a different name (quicker), or you adapt `attachSignin` to detect wich of your buttons is clicked and react differently (cleaner), maybe by using `resp.name.givenName` or another attribute of `resp`.